# Is there a way to embed an executable binary in a shell script without extra tools?

Tags: scripting, executable, binary

I'm looking for a way to have an executable binary hardwired into a script. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
...some shell code
execute binary:
    >>>
        binary
        code
        ...
    <<<
...some more shell code possibly
```

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491738/6631810), which uses `uuencode` and is good. But it depends on `shrutils`, which seem to be an extra, as they're not included by default on my Debian.

I've been thinking of having the binary encoded with `base64` and then decoding it and *somehow* executing, possibly without creating any temp files. I remember there was a library that's responsible for executing things, but forgot what it was.

It might be the best to have a construct as simple as this execute:

```
$ <(base64 out | base64 -d)
bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you looking for no-tool-support-needed to run, or no-tool-support-needed to create?

Comment: Consider also: putting the shell script inside of the binary-executable.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor To run. Creation would be another question. And so I'd rather embed the executable in a script, not the other way round, to be able to modify the "packaging" easily.

Comment: Note that `uudecode`, contrary to `base64` is a standard POSIX command. So while on Debian it may be more likely to find a `base64` command than `uudecode`, it may be the contrary on many other systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
unpack() {
    tail +9 "$0" > /tmp/xxx.$$
    chmod +x /tmp/xxx.$$
}
unpack
/tmp/xxx.$$ <add args here>
rm /tmp/xxx.$$
exit
<add the binary here>
```

If you don't like to have binary data in the script, you may encode it and replace `cat` by the related decoder.

Note that you need to replace the `+9` by the line number where the binary starts in case that you modify the script to be of different length.

If your `tail` implementation does not support the argument `+9`, try `-n +9` instead.

If you are in fear of clobbering an existing /tmp file, try to use `mktemp(1)` to create the tmp filename.

Note that this method was used by the upgrade scripts for the `SunPro` compiler suite that included the compressed tar archive with the whole upgrade and some shell code to manage the handling around that.

Comment: I used `base64` instead of `cat`, as the executable code doesn't look good in a script.

Comment: Use a longer marker, `EOF` is a bit short, and the binary code may trigger it.

Comment: Well, the marker must appear directly after a newline.

Comment: @Schily so that is 4 bytes \nEOF. You could make it longer and safer, with little waste of space.

Comment: That approach would only work with `zsh`. Other shells would strip or choke on NUL bytes. Even with `zsh`, that means the binary file would have to end in a newline character.

Comment: Uups you are right, I'll prepare a working version.

Comment: Now I have the code that was in use by Sun. Sorry for not verifying what I had in memory.

Comment: I'd add some quotes around variables, `< "$0"` to avoid other problems with with weird file names, `tail -n +9` for POSIX compliance, check for command failures, use noclobber to limit (not eliminate unfortunately as noclobber has a  race condition) the risk of someone planting malware in place of that not-very-random file name,

Comment: You have been too late for the `-n +9` but the other hints are OK.

Comment: Strangely, I only see a `tail` but there is no `cat`

Answer (score 3):

Starting with

`aShellScript`
`aBinaryExecutable`

do

```
zip binary.zip aBinaryExecutable
cat aShellScript binary.zip > hybrid
chmod +x hybrid
```

I have missed out what to put in the script, to extract and run the binary, but note `hybrid` is a valid zip-file, and a valid shell script, the shell script can unzip itself and get the binary-executable (but not the shell script).

## Advantage

Is robust: The file is a valid zip, and a valid shell script (so long as you exit before trying to interpret the garbage at the end).

## Disadvantage

The end of script is ugly.

## Why it works

- `shell` starts interpreting from start of file. (All offsets are symbolic.)
- `zip` starts interpreting from end of file. All offsets are relative.

Comment: I've not tested it and `zip` is not installed on Debian by default, but +1 for idea. I assume it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a marker tag at the end of the script. Let's assume "ONLY_BINARY_AFTER_THIS_POINT:" is my marker. Your script can contain these lines.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# my_script.sh


# find the line number where my tag is in this file
line_number=$(grep -na -m1 "^ONLY_BINARY_AFTER_THIS_POINT:$" "$0"|cut -d':' -f1)
# next line is where contents of my binary file starts, use mathematical expansion to increase it by 1
$((line_number+=1))
# dump everything after $line_number of this script into somewhere I can access
tail -n +"${line_number}" "$0" > /tmp/my_binary_file.bin
# do further processing on /tmp/my_binary_file.bin


# don't forget the new line here and don't type in anything after this point
#                            ↓
ONLY_BINARY_AFTER_THIS_POINT:
```

then you can append the binary file to your script by

```bsh
cat my_script.sh my_binary_file.bin > my_appended_script.sh
```

Important is that you should only have a new line, and **nothing else** before appending binary file to your script. Moreover, if you edit the script after appending, you should be careful about your selection of text editor. Text editor might change some characters when you are saving the script.

**note:** You can also directly append to your script, but if you add redirection '>', instead of an append '>>' your script would be overwritten.